# how to use $match after $group in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 4 products. I want to know the count of `product-4` for users who has `product-1` or `product-2`

Sample data:

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "product_type": "product-1"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "product_type": "product-4"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "product_type": "product-4"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    "product_type": "product-1"
  }
]
```

user-1 has two `product-4` and one `product-1` (that counts 2)

user-2 has only `product-1`, but no `product-4` (hence that does not count)

*This is how I tried*

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      product_type: {
        $in: [
          "product-1​",
          "product-2",
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$user_id",
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      user_id: { $in: "$_id"}, // I want to use $group's result in here
      product_type: "product-4",
    },
  }
]);
```

Expected results are:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "count": 0
  }
]
```

Note:
I dont have a backend, I have to this using mongodb only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: "$user_id", data: {$push: "$product_type"}}},
  {$match: {$expr: {$or: [
          {$in: ["product-1", "$data"]},
          {$in: ["product-2", "$data"]}
        ]}}},
  {$project: {
      count: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$data",
            cond: {$eq: ["$$this", "product-4"]}
          }
        }
      }
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c-HbzlYAtTD)

Comment: I think, I did not get the same result as you did

Comment: What are the results that you expect for these 4 documents?

Comment: count should be 2 in user-1. count should be 0 in user-2

Comment: Actually, It is not I want. I want to count product-4 if the user have product-1 or product-2

Comment: A sample output would have been helpful. But I think [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UQImzW5oKTJ), a count of distinct products per user, is what OP is looking for?

Comment: I updated the answer to what I think the OP wants